# Light event in WinAPI / C++

Tags: c++, performance, winapi, events, synchronization

Is there some light (thus fast) event in WinAPI / C++ ? Particularly, I'm interested in minimizing the time spent on waiting for the event (like `WaitForSingleObject()`) when the event is set. Here is a code example to clarify further what I mean:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  const int64_t nIterations = 10 * 1000 * 1000;
  HANDLE hEvent = CreateEvent(nullptr, true, true, nullptr);
  auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  for (int64_t i = 0; i < nIterations; i++) {
    WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, INFINITE);
  }
  auto elapsed = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start;
  double nSec = 1e-6 * std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(elapsed).count();
  printf("%.3lf Ops/sec\n", nIterations / nSec);
  return 0;
}
```

On 3.85GHz Ryzen 1800X I'm getting 7209623.405 operations per second, meaning 534 CPU clocks (or 138.7 nanoseconds) are spent on average for a check whether the event is set.

However, I want to use the event in performance-critical code where most of the time the event is actually set, so it's just a check for a special case and in that case the control flow goes to code which is not performance-critical (because this situation is seldom).

WinAPI events which I know (created with `CreateEvent`) are heavy-weight because of security attributes and names. They are intended for inter-process communication. Perhaps `WaitForSingleObject()` is so slow because it switches from user to kernel mode and back, even when the event is set. Furthermore, this function has to behave differently for manual- and auto-reset events, and a check for the type of the event takes time too.

I know that a fast user-mode mutex (spin lock) can be implemented with [`atomic_flag`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag) . Its spinning loop can be extended with a [`std::this_thread::yield()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/yield) in order to let other threads run while spinning.

With the event I wouldn't like a complete equivalent of a spin-lock, because when the event is not set, it may take substantial time till it becomes set again. If every thread that needs the event set start spinning till it's set again, that would be an epic waste of CPU electricity (though shouldn't affect system performance if they call `std::this_thread::yield`)

So I would rather like an analogy of a critical section, which usually just does the work in user mode and when it realizes it needs to wait (out of spins), it switches to kernel mode and waits on a heavy synchronization object like a mutex.

UPDATE1: I've found that .NET has [`ManualResetEventSlim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualreseteventslim(v=vs.110).aspx) , but couldn't find an equivalent in WinAPI / C++.

UPDATE2: because there were details of event usage requested, here they are. I'm implementing a knowledge base that can be switched between regular and maintenance mode. Some operations are maintenance-only, some operations are regular-only, some can work in both modes, but of them some are faster in maintenance and some are faster in regular mode. Upon its start each operation needs to know whether it is in maintenance or regular mode, as the logic changes (or the operation refuses to execute at all). From time to time user can request a switch between maintenance and regular mode. This is rare. When this request arrives, no new operations in the old mode can start (a request to do so fails) and the app waits for the current operations in the old mode to finish, then it switches mode. So light event is a part of this data structure: the operations except mode switching have to be fast, so they need to set/reset/wait event quickly.

Comment: `So I would rather like an analogy of a critical section` - and why not use it or say new Slim Reader/Writer  Locks ? or you need interprocess synchronization ?

Comment: Is this an auto-reset or a manual-reset event?  Is there more than one thread waiting on the event?

Comment: in windows exist different synchronization functions, which try do most work in user mode, and enter to kernel only when need wait - critical sections, slim rw locks, wait on adress change, etc. all it only for in process synchronization. possible of course and implement custom syncronization solution based on interlocked operations and wait on events when need wait. but this only have sense if no any existing match to your task. because unclear your real task and for what need synchronization hard give now more concrete advice. kernel mode objects require enter to kernel and this is heavy op

Comment: IOCP(Input/output completion port)?

Comment: @RbMm , I don't need interprocess synchronization. Could you elaborate (perhaps in an answer with code example) how Slim Reader/Writer Lock can replace an event?

Comment: @HarryJohnston , for now I need manual-reset event. Yes, many threads can be waiting on it.

Comment: Why don't you have a look at the [implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/ManualResetEventSlim.cs,07ccbd30abe2a211) of `ManualResetEventSlim` class?

Comment: It should be trivial to combine an `atomic_bool` with a manual-reset event object.  When you set or reset the event, set or reset the bool as well.  Before waiting on the event, check the bool; if it is set, don't bother with the wait.  (I imagine that `atomic_bool` is implemented efficiently, but you could use the Win32 interlocked operations instead if you preferred.)

Comment: impossible give you advice - what and how better use, without knowledge - for what. what is you target goal, which code need synchronization or notifications or ?

Comment: @RbMm , I think I've explained how that light event is intended to be used: like in my code example, the event is usually set, so I would like waiting on it to be as fast as possible when the event is set (thus actually nothing to wait).

Comment: @RbMm, typically the goal would be to be able to pause whatever it is that the thread(s) in question are doing.  So, for example, in a number-crunching application there might be a GUI with a "pause" button and a "resume" button, and when the user hits "pause" the threads that are actually doing the work have to stop and wait for the user to hit "resume".  (Serge, is that about right?)

Comment: the `WaitOnAddress`, `WakeByAddress*` look like exactly you want (but i not sure that need), but this api only from win8 exist.  @HarryJohnston - what you say about atomic_bool with a manual-reset event object - not 100% correct can work. `atomic_bool` or interlocked operations on bool not need here, this nothing give to us. what we really need - interlocked change bool and event at once. as atomic operation. otherwise can be what i try explain in answer.

Comment: @HarryJohnston , the scenario is right in terms of the pattern how the event is used in my app. My app is a little more complicated than that, thus the light event is just a part of more complicated synchronization. I'll add the details to the question.

Answer (score 2):

begin from win8 the best solution for you use [`WaitOnAddress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706898(v=vs.85).aspx) (in place `WaitForSingleObject`, [`WakeByAddressAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706899(v=vs.85).aspx) (work like `SetEvent` for *NotificationEvent*) and [`WakeByAddressSingle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706900(v=vs.85).aspx) (work like *SynchronizationEvent* ). more read - [WaitOnAddress lets you create a synchronization object](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160823-00/?p=94145)

implementation can be next:

```
class LightEvent 
{
    BOOLEAN _Signaled;
public:
    LightEvent(BOOLEAN Signaled)
    {
        _Signaled = Signaled;
    }

    void Reset()
    {
        _Signaled = FALSE;
    }

    void Set(BOOLEAN bWakeAll)
    {
        _Signaled = TRUE;
        (bWakeAll ? WakeByAddressAll : WakeByAddressSingle)(&_Signaled);
    }

    BOOL Wait(DWORD dwMilliseconds = INFINITE)
    {
        BOOLEAN Signaled = FALSE;

        while (!_Signaled)
        {
            if (!WaitOnAddress(&_Signaled, &Signaled, sizeof(BOOLEAN), dwMilliseconds))
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
};
```

don't forget add `Synchronization.lib` for linker input.

code for this new api very effective, they not create internal kernel objects for wait (like event) but use new api `ZwAlertThreadByThreadId` `ZwWaitForAlertByThreadId` special design for this targets.

how implement this yourself, before win8 ? for first look trivial - boolen varitable + event handle. and must look like:

```
void Set()
{
  SetEvent(_hEvent);
   // Sleep(1000); // simulate thread innterupted here
  _Signaled = true;
}

void Reset()
{
  _Signaled = false;
  // Sleep(1000); // simulate thread innterupted here
  ResetEvent(_hEvent);
}

void Wait(DWORD dwMilliseconds = INFINITE)
{
  if(!_Signaled) WaitForSingleObject(_hEvent);
}
```

but this code really incorrect. problem that we do 2 operation in `Set` (`Reset`) - change state of `_Signaled` and `_hEvent`. and no way do this from user mode as atomic/interlocked operation. this mean that thread can be interrupted between this two operation. assume that 2 different threads in concurrent call `Set` and `Reset`. in most case operation will be executed in next order for example:

```
  SetEvent(_hEvent);
  _Signaled = true;
  _Signaled = false;
  ResetEvent(_hEvent);
```

here all ok. but possible and next order (uncomment one `Sleep` for test this)

```
  SetEvent(_hEvent);
  _Signaled = false;
  ResetEvent(_hEvent);
  _Signaled = true;
```

as result `_hEvent` will be in reset state, when `_Signaled` is `true`.

implement this as atomic yourself, without os support will be not simply, however possible. but i be first look for usage of this - for what ? are event like behavior this is exactly you need for task ?

Comment: The set/reset operations only need to be atomic with respect to one another, not with respect to any other threads, so that can be done with a critical section.  (It may not even be necessary; it is likely that only one particular thread will be modifying the state of the event.)  WaitOnAddress saves you some work, if you don't need to support Windows 7.  But it certainly isn't *necessary*.

Comment: ... I think the variable should be atomic or accessed via interlocked operations, though, to ensure that `_Signaled = true;` can be seen promptly by the other CPU cores.  At the very least it needs to be volatile, to ensure the compiler won't optimize out the test if the Wait() function gets inlined.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - about atomic on `_Signaled` - i tnink we nothing gain here - yes possible situation when we in concurrent call `Wait` and `Set` - that we already execute `_Signaled = true;` but thread which call `Wait` yet read `false` from `_Signaled` and go to wait on event (which anyway we set in this case). but this is possible even if we use atomic/interlocked operations for `_Signaled = true;` - the thread which call `Wait` can anyway read state of `_Signaled` jsut **before** we atomic/interlocked set it to `true`.

Comment: from another side if frequently use `lock` prefix (when we modify `_Signaled`) this can degrade performance.if `Set` and `Reset` always will be called from the same thread - in this case yes,no problems with interrupt between `_Signaled` and `_hEvent` modifications. however for me still unclear how/for what all this will be used. say if in concurent will be called `Wait` and `Reset` and `Wait` will be executed just before reset, when `_Signaled` yet `true` - this will be ok - do something in working thread when by fact `_hEvent` by fact already will be reseted ?

Comment: may be OP simply need code like this ? `do 
  {
   if (_bTaskToDo) DoSomething(); else WaitForSingleObject(_hEvent);
  } while (!bQuit);` and `set(){ _bTaskToDo = TRUE; SetEvent(_hEvent);}` and `reset(){ ResetEvent(_hEvent);_bTaskToDo = FALSE; }`

Comment: (this question i not see, skip. however can be interesting. thank you )

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is very good if you can drop support of Windows 7.

However on Win7, if you set/reset the event many times from multiple threads, but only need to sleep rarely, the proposed method is quite slow.

Instead, I use a boolean guarded by a critical section, with condition variable to wake / sleep.

The wait method will go to the kernel for sleep on [SleepConditionVariableCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleepconditionvariablecs) API, that’s expected and what you want.

However set & reset methods will work entirely in user mode: setting a single boolean variable is very fast, i.e. in 99% of cases, the critical section will do it’s user-mode lock free magic.